# I want to know when the AD9235BRUZ-65 outputs data? I can't make sense of the datasheet or find a way to simulate it

Tags: fpga, adc, components, component-selection

I need to know when data is output from the AD9235BRUZ-65 digital pins. I need this to create a type of handshake with a FPGA.

[Datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1697968.pdf).

Comment: See figure 2: Data is valid 6 ns after each clock edge until 2 ns after the following edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure two in the datasheet shows that analog value from 7 clock cycles ago is guaranteed to be on the output pins on the falling clock edge.  As long as you stick to the clock requirements in Table 3, that's all you should have to worry about.